# No dual boot option HP laptop win 10

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, hp

I installed Ubuntu on my new HP 15 bw laptop alongside Windows 10. When the installation of Ubuntu was done and I restarted my laptop there was an option to choose between Windows and Ubuntu but every time since my PC has automatically started Windows.

I have tried:

- Turning off fast start
- Booting linux from USB stick and installing `grub`
- Looking for an option of Ubuntu in boot order section (there wasn't)
- Installing EasyBCD (says: `EasyBCD has detected that your machine is currently booting in EFI mode...`)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10, when booted by EFI, "helpfully" restores the default EFI boot entry to what I thinks is the one true default (ie itself).
You can change what Windows considers to be default by running (in an Administrator command prompt) something similar to this:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

The exact path (after the word "path") may vary. I believe the above is the default for a Ubuntu install though.

Note that this will be reset with EVERY build update (approximately 6 months apart for normal users). You need to re-run this EVERY time these major updates install.

Comment: Thank you but still nothing. edit: How do I know the right path?

Comment: If you have activated secure boot you'll need `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`